# PHP Sessions - Best practices for logout

Tags: php, security, session

I'm working on a PHP Application that uses the `session_destroy()` method to log a user out of the system, because it is considered good practice to destroy all session information on logout.

However, I'd like to store some information like "Last login date, Last Username" etc indefinitely (until the browser's cache/cookies are flushed). This information will be used to build subtle personalisation features for the user/people using the same browser.

I cannot store this data on the server because this ***information needs to be identified with the Browser***, not a User of the system, and I have no data that uniquely identifies a browser reliably.

What is the best/recommended way of going about this? I'm currently thinking multiple sessions, and using one of them to store this kind of information, and not destroying it.

Any good advice would be appreciated. Security is a concern for this application. Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Bottom line: Is not destroying a session completely opening up security risks like session hijacking?**

Comment: `Is not destroying a session completely opening up security risks like session hijacking?` Yes. It does.

Answer (score 3):

It is better (and **you have to**) to store the `last_login` and `last_login_ip` in the `users` table in the database than in the client side. What if the browser is crashed, or if the user logs in using another browser / computer.

The `session_destroy()` is the right one. Or if you wanna do more, you can reset the session, **which is not recommended** and call `session_destroy()` like this:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

But I would recommend clearing only the particular session information that you have set using the application. Say, for example:

```
unset($_SESSION["user"]);
```

---

> because remember, the data I'm storing here would be used after the user has been logged out, which means I have no way of identifying the user

You are storing the data on the database, which means, there's no way, you can mistake. The comment is crazy. Let me give an example for what you said first. Consider the `last_login` and `last_login_ip`, and you do this:

```
Query_The_Server("UPDATE `users` SET `last_login`=NOW(), `last_login_ip`='{$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]}' WHERE `user_id`={$_SESSION["user"]["user_id"]}");
```

Now tell me, how can the above thing fail?

---

> Example: in the login page, I want to say "Last logged in user on this machine was: John".

This calls for a privacy issue. Say, for eg., I log into the app, and logout, and my friend logs in or some other person, who's waiting to hit on me, logs in. He finds that I have logged in previously and this might be a privacy issue. Think about it.

But still, if this is what you wanna do, then yes, do not use `session_destroy()`, instead use `unset($_SESSION["user"]);` or whatever you stored to identify the user and don't touch the `last_user`.

Another idea would be:

```
$_SESSION["last_user"] = $_SESSION["user"]
unset($_SESSION["user"]);                         // Technically logging out.
unset($_SESSION["last_user"]["private_stuff"]);   // Make sure you clear the private stuff.
```

Comment: Is not destroying the session completely a potential security risk though? The application needs to be prone to session hijacking etc

Comment: @AsjadAthick I don't understand. How can you store data in database and you cannot retrieve after logging out?

Comment: the data I'm trying to store will be used in the application prior to login. Example: in the login page, I want to say "Last logged in user on this machine was: John". 

Because I dont have any data that uniquely identifies the browser on the server side, I cannot do any database logging

Comment: @AsjadAthick That's a crazy privacy thing. Why do you wanna do that? `:O`

Comment: @AsjadAthick If that's the thing you wanna do, yes, do not use `session_destroy()`, instead use `unset($_SESSION["user"]);` or whatever you stored to identify the user and don't touch the `last_user`.

Comment: while I understand the privacy concerns, I'm simply using this data to build personalisation features that the user can turn off if they really wanted lol. And because its all client side, its all local to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the data into some form of permanent storage, as session data is only stored until the user closes their browser.

Then get that data from the medium and display it until another user logs in.

Then run:

```
session_destroy();
```