# Removing Expired Sessions

Tags: php, session-cookies

This is my first time posting. I believe I've searched through a bit of the other forums to see if my question has already been asked, but I'm still left scratching my head. I know there's a lot of postings about expired sessions, but I'm thinking in terms of a specific scenario, I guess.

A user is logged into the Dashboard and goes to a page. It sits idle for how ever long, then the garbage collector does its thing and clears the session.

Now, if the user goes back to the Dashboard and clicks to go to another page, I would like to have the user return to the index page - effectively log out.

I have a logout page that the user can go to when they choose to log out. I record some data in the database, remove the session and redirects back to the home page.

I would like to first check if the session is indeed alive. If not, destroy it and redirect to the home page. Otherwise, delete it.

But my question is, if the garbage collector had already cleared the session, do I even need to destroy it?

```
<?php 

  session_start( );

  if( !isset( $_SESSION['session'] ) ) { 
     session_destroy( );
     header( "Location: /index.php" );
  }
  else {

     // ... log the data I need in the database ...

     $_SESSION['session'] = array( );

     if( ini_get( "session.use_cookies" ) ) {
       $params = session_get_cookie_params( );
       setcookie( session_name( ), '', time( ) - 42000,
                  $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                  $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] );
     }

     session_destroy( );
     header( "Location: /index.php" );    
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start()` and `session_destroy()` aren't working with the garbage collector the way you think they are. They're utilizing internal adapters to allow PHP to talk to a persistence layer (generally the filesystem, in this case, the browsers cookies), to extract session information.

What you're doing when you call `session_destroy()`, is you're instructing your session ADAPTER to destroy the session, not so much PHP. PHP garbage collects the session memory usage constantly, but still maintains reference to the adapters persistence of the session data.

So, yes, you have to call it, unless you destroyed it already.

Comment: So, the garbage collector clears the session from memory, but because the session is a cookie, the session cookie still remains and therefore I still need to destroy it manually?

Comment: Yes. `session_destroy()` (attempts to) fully remove references of the session, its ID, and its storage of session data for that ID. A great example of this in action is having PHP files that don't use `session_start()` at them. - The session is there, it's just not being read, because you never initialized the adapter to pull the data. Check out the php.ini setting `session.save_handler` to learn more about some of the cool stuff here! - If this answer has answered your question sufficiently, please ✔ Accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question: no, you don't have to destroy session yourself.

`session_start()` will always start or resume a session, and this session will always be "alive". Whether this session will have a flag of logged user or not is up to you though.

To determine user's logged in status you could just save some "flag" into session, for example: `userId`. Then, right after `session_start()` (except on login page) you can check this session variable. If it exists then user is logged in. If it doesn't, that means either new user or user with expired session cookie (logged out). In both cases you just redirect to login page. That's all.

Also, calling `session_destroy()` from usual code [isn't recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: I know session_destroy( ) destroys all sessions, but when I was researching how to handle destroying sessions, it came up a lot. For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508295/php-sessions-best-practices-for-logout

Comment: @B.Chu `session_destroy()` **does not** destroy all sessions. It just destroys all data associated with current session.

Comment: @B.Chu The important thing to note from @Styx is that `session_destroy()` isn't concurrency safe. Including that, `session_regenerate_id()` is also unsafe. To that end, ideally you will eventually destroy a session, but it's considered safer to first expire a sessions usability before expiring it, to ensure that you can safely delete it without causing multiple creation calls (resulting in unused session IDs) - There's some great session libraries in PHP that help you with this, check em out friend.

Comment: @syntaqx You're missing important part of original question: "A user is logged into the Dashboard and goes to a page. It sits idle for how ever long, then the garbage collector does its thing and clears the session.". If garbage collection has already cleaned session, then it doesn't make sense to "destroy" already empty session. That's what I'm trying to say to OP.