# php session count increases always

Tags: php, session

My main objective is to get the count of currently active session.
My code is -

```
$count = count(scandir(ini_get("session.save_path")));
```

But the value is increasing only. Th site may not have any active users. Why `$count` is not decreasing in that case?

Comment: Likely because there are still expired session data files, that have not yet been cleaned up by the _garbage collector_. _“My main objective is to get the count of currently active session.”_ - the approach you have chosen, is not really suitable for that to begin with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132603/removing-expired-sessions

Comment: What is the value of the session timeout timer session.gc_maxlifetime?

Comment: @Mark maxlifetime is 7200.

Comment: Ok, so the garbage collector should delete them after 2 hours (7200 seconds).
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: also this could help: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520237/2932052)